# How can I speed up or replace code to combine close contours?

Tags: opencv, contour, emgucv

My problem is combining nearby contours at a reasonable speed.

I start with a CV8U single-channel greyscale mat containing an image of a large, closed shape. Sprouting on the inside of this shape is a short curve. My mission is to get the curve only into a vector of points.

So I threshold my mat and call FindContours. The result is a vector of many contours. Some are noise, including bits of the large shape that I didn't quite manage to mask out. But several are parts of my curve. The problem is that the curve - continuous in the raw image - is fragmented into many contours by FindContours. To fix this, I find the largest contour, which is always a part of my curve, and search for other nearby contours. If I find any, I join them together, and repeat.

By the end, I have a single vector of points containing my curve. It works. But all the looping and iteration makes it stupidly slow.

What alternative approach would retain the output (a vector of points representing my curve) but run fast?

```
Private vpcurve As VectorOfPoint
...
    GrowCurve(FindContoursOutput, inc, BiggestContourInFindContoursOutput)
...
Private Sub GrowCurve(ContoursToCheck As VectorOfVectorOfPoint, ContoursIncluded() As Boolean, StartContour As Integer)
    vpcurve.Push(ContoursToCheck(StartContour).ToArray)
    ContoursIncluded(StartContour) = True
    For j = ContoursToCheck.Size - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Not ContoursIncluded(j) Then
            If contoursClose(ContoursToCheck, j, StartContour) Then
                GrowCurve(ContoursToCheck, ContoursIncluded, j)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Function contoursClose(cnt As VectorOfVectorOfPoint, index1 As Integer, index2 As Integer) As Boolean
    For i As Integer = cnt(index1).Size - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Dim p1 As Point = cnt(index1)(i)
        For j As Integer = cnt(index2).Size - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Dim p2 As Point = cnt(index2)(j)
            If (Math.Pow(p1.X - p2.X, 2) + Math.Pow(p1.Y - p2.Y, 2)) < 30 Then 'arbitrary  pixel distance
                contoursClose = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    Next
    contoursClose = False
End Function
```

Comment: Start by your thresholding. Could you improve your binarization? Does an adaptive threshold leads to a better result? Is color segmentation a possibility?  Maybe you post your source image.

Comment: Thanks. The image is a frame in a greyscale video. I've tried adjusting the threshold and this can fix an individual frame, but this then causes problems with other frames. I haven't tried the adaptive threshold: will do, and report back.